# How to access firebase realtimedb in NUXT js

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, nuxt.js

We have a realtimedb in firebase that has data as follows:

[image]

On our nuxt page we have the following method:

```js
async getDb () {
      const messageRef = this.$firebase.database.ref('test')
      try {
        const snapshot = await messageRef.once('value')
        alert(snapshot.val().message)
      } catch (e) {
        alert(e)
      }
    },
```

That is run by this in mounted like this:

```
mounted () {
    this.getDb()
  },
```

I keep getting this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'database')

Am I doing something wrong? I have all of the firebase config in Nuxt.config.js and suth is working fine. I also added the realtimedb to services:

```
 services: {
  realtimeDb: true,
  auth: {
    ssr: true,
    // it is recommended to configure either a mutation or action but you can set both
    initialize: {
      onAuthStateChangedMutation: 'ON_AUTH_STATE_CHANGED_MUTATION'
      // onAuthStateChangedAction: 'onAuthStateChangedAction'
    }
  },
```

How do you actually access the data from the realtimedb so I can display the test array on my page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `$firebase` which is not included in this [documentation](https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/guide/usage#fire). To grant access to your Realtime Database use the following:

```
$fire.database
```

or

```
$fireModule.database
```

**Note:**

> If you are using `nuxt/firebase` **version 6** use `realtimeDb` and `database` for **version 7** in services of **nuxt.config.js**, see this [link](https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/community/migrate/) for more details.